"She has been waited for me" change this sentence to question form to get "for me" as the answer

She has been waited for me

What is the question form to get for me as the answer?

Your sentence is not grammatical and doesn't make sense.   Perhaps you meant to say, "She has been waiting for me".  Is this what you mean?

There is mistake in the sentence. Is it "She has been waited for by me." Answer - by me. She has been waiting for me. Answer - for me. Please correct your sentence, whatever correction is there.

In other words, please check the original question: is it been waiting or by me

This doesn't make sense:

She has been waited for me.

I believe you're trying to say

She has been waiting for me.


She's been waiting for me.

A possible question for that answer is
Who has she been waiting for?

The OP's answer suggests that all attempts to guess at a similar idiomatic meaning were wrong, and I would suggest it was wrong to offer guesswork-answers.

Assuming you mean "She has been waiting for me" then the most natural would be "Who has she been waiting for". The natural answer would be "me" but "for me" wouldn't be unnatural.

The OP's answer suggests that all attempts to guess at a similar idiomatic meaning were wrong, and I would suggest it was wrong to offer guesswork-answers.

Guessing the corrected sentence:

If the sentence is:
She has waited for me.
The interrogative form is :
For whom has she waited ?
Answer: For me
If the sentence is:
She has been waited for by me.
The interrogative form is :
By whom has she been waited for?
Answer: By me


Please don't introduce new words when editing the original question, it invalidates other people's answers. P.S This answer is overly formal, changes the meaning of the original sentence and uses the passive voice, which is not needed here.

"Answer: By me” But the OP says the answer must be for me.

@Mari-LouA There is some mistake. The sentence in the question is wrong. If the verb phrase "has been waited", is correct, only "by" needs to be added making it a sentence in the passive voice. Otherwise "waited" has to be changed to waiting. Everyone is guessing and answering until OP sets it right.

I'm not guessing. And neither should you. In my humble opinion, the OP will not be coming back to clarify

The OP's answer suggests that all attempts to guess at a similar idiomatic meaning were wrong, and I would suggest it was wrong to offer guesswork-answers.
